# Find $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\frac{(x+y)\sec(x+y)-x\sec x}y$

Tags: limits

How do I solve $\lim\limits_{y\to0}\frac{(x+y)\sec(x+y)-x\sec x}y$. I've tried it a few times but I don't quite get the right answer. Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: What is $u$?  Are you trying to find the limit as $(x,y) goes to the origin?

Comment: can you use L'Hospital

Comment: Hint. $x$ is a constant, and the limit of the numerator tends to zero, so the limit should be zero

Comment: @mannav That statement is false.  The indeterminate form does not have $0$ as its limit.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I was wondering who was going to make this (idiotic) suggestion first. Kudos, you win the prize of "Hey, let us apply a rule without understanding what it is about".

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Write the derivative of $x\sec(x)$ using the limit definition of the derivative.

Can you proceed now?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{(x+h)\sec(x+h)-x\sec x}h=x\cdot\dfrac{\sec(x+h)-\sec x}h+\sec(x+h)$$

Now $\dfrac{\sec(x+h)-\sec x}h=\dfrac1{\cos x\cos(x+h)}\cdot\dfrac{\cos x-\cos(x+h)}h$

Now use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html), $\cos x-\cos(x+h)=2\sin\dfrac{2x+h}2\sin\dfrac h2$

and $\lim_{u\to0}\dfrac{\sin u}u=1$

Comment: At the end, you could use derivative of cosine instead.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, Wanted to use limit to calculate derivative, not the the other way round. Actually the required answer is as we all know is $$\dfrac{d(x\sec x)}{dx}$$